# UINavigationBar to a higher xib layer index

Tags: objective-c, ios

Similar to how `z-index` works in HTML, I want to make my `UINavigationBar` be on the highest layer so that everything in my `scroll view` goes *underneath* it.

I currently just have a `xib` with a `UINavigationBar` located at the top with a `UIScrollView` below it vertically that has `Bounce Vertically` *checked*. When you *slide* the `scroll view` the content from the `scroll view` will appear to be above the `UINavigationBar` and covers it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a UIViewController I would suggest using this code :

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = false;
```

But if you are using a plain UIView I will refer you to the UIView documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIView
Look for the `@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSArray *subviews` and other subviews related method.
You can order your view relative to each other with those method.

Comment: I looked at the article and seeing how it works - I simply removed my navbar from my xib and dragged another one out. That means the new one was on the highest layer (which is what I wanted). I re-setup the linkage and viola problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the zPosition of navigationBar to the topmost layer as below

```
navigationController.navigationBar.layer.zPosition =[[self.view subviews] count];
```